# Matrix-vector-constant multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

**Problem:**

I have the following matrix: $$H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
and the following vector:
$$S=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}$$
What is $H*S$?

**Work:**

First I simplified $H$: $$H=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$
Then I multiplied it by the vector:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Did I do this correctly? If not, where did I make the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, but it's much faster not to multiply the constant into the matrix:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha + \beta\\\alpha - \beta\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Oh, good to know...so you just multiply the constant after multiplying the matrix? Okay, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's just simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did it right.

Trivia, the matrix $H$ corresponds to Hadamard gate.

Comment: Yeah, I know it corresponds to the Hadamard gate - I wanted to make sure I was doing the calculation with it right. =) Thanks!